# Android, Dagger, Dependency injection design pattern for middleware networking classes

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I am not quite sure how to put this in a specific question but let me try and I apologize for wrong explanation or wording on beforehand.

I started learning dependency injection pattern specifically in Dagger 2 and browsed some examples.  My goal is to inject networking (middleware) classes, primarily for tests.  Examples I have seen so far are making 1 interface which has all networking as sub classes and 1 module class to bind the interface, then Application class is creating an object graph.  Is this a common pattern ?

I am imagining, suppose there are 10 networking classes, most of the cases 1 screen only requires 1 or a few middleware classes.  However what I saw was injecting whole middleware in Application.  I can say it seems easy to switch classes between production and test by a few line, but is it a good idea to making the graph with whole networking classes on booting up the Application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should inject your dependencies (middleware classes) not into Android Application class, but into concrete places of code where these dependencies are needed. Into Activity, Fragment, controller etc.

For example if you have Twitter API configured as dependency, you may inject it into concrete class like TweetComposerActivity. BTW here is a link to the Jake Wharton presentation, it was very useful to me: https://plus.google.com/+JakeWharton/posts/SRaaHenwLfj